# Why use 'try' ' catch' 'finally' to handle exception

Tags: exception, try-catch

The teacher said that using exception testing can improve the robustness of the program. Clearly it is true.

But there is a paradox here.

If I didn't realize that this section of the program may have exception. I wouldn't use try{} either!
If I realize that this program may be has exception, why don't I fix this program to make it more robust?

For example，simple function

```
function c=div(a,b)
 c=a/b;
end
```

If b=null or b=0 or b is char ，there will be an exception, why do I have to use

```
function c=div(a,b)
try{c=a/b;
   }
catch (children class){…………
                   } 
catch(parent class){…………
                }
catch(exception e){…………
               }        
end
```

**Why do not I use a switch case + @NotEmpty @NotNull isDigit() to verify that the input parameters？**

**If you find that the bucket is leaking**

**try catch helps you pour the leaked water back into the bucket**

**But why don't I plug the bucket hole?**

**If you don't notice the bucket is leaking**

**try catch doesn't help much either**

**this is my confusion**

Comment: In the specific case shown it would indeed make more sense to me to validate the inputs before trying to use them.  If the inputs are invalid, depending on the needs of the function, I'd either return a default response or (more likely) throw an exception.  The consuming code would probably want to handle that exception, but that's really up to that code.  But then what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Exceptions are actually your friend, and they come in two flavors: checked and unchecked. Unchecked (i.e. runtime) exceptions are typically the result of programming error, and it's usually best to leave these uncaught except by top-level handlers for exceptions (e.g. command dispatchers), so that programming errors are noticed and resolved. Checked exceptions represent failure conditions outside of the program's control (e.g. IO, OS signals, bad input), which allow you to react should those situations arise. These tend to be handled closer to the site the error arises from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about knowing or not knowing in advance that you program may throw an exception in some particular code block. It's about being able to recover if "something" happens. For example, if the error causes your application to crash, it results in negative consequences:

1. Some opened resources may not get closed properly (depends on OS and a bunch of other factors).
2. User experience is bad: people don't like seing fatal crashes of the apps they are using.

However, if you wrap your logic in a `try-catch` block, you are able to recover from getting an error (not always, of course, - depends on the error).

Then you may ask: "Why not just wrap the whole program in an uber-`try-catch` block"? Well, you can. But the things is that most of the time "recovery" depends on two things:

1. What type of error did happen?
2. Where exactly did it happen?

Depending on the answers, you will try to restore the app flow one way or another, which would be problematic - if not impossible - if you just had an ultimate `try-catch` wrapping your whole app.

Your follow-up question may be: "But then, how do I decide on the granularity of my `try-catch`es"? How many of them should I have across my codebase? How frequently should I insert them? Should I wrap every single line into its own `try-catch`? Or it is fine to have it per function/method?

Well, these are good questions, because there's no silver bullet here. It really depends on your code and on the specific programming language you are using. For example, some PLs (like Java) have so-called "checked exceptions": if some function defines a checked exception, then you **must** catch it when you call this function (or later, at some point, upper in the call stack). Some languages don't have this concept. Also, keep in mind different paradigms: procedural programming, functional programming, OOP, etc. All of this impacts your strategy of handling exceptions. As a rule of thumb, you may follow a recommendation that whenever you open some resource (file, DB connection, etc.) - wrap it in `try-catch-finally` and make sure to close this resource in the `finally` block. Some languages (like Java) even have a special syntax for this, called [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.    "It's not about knowing or not knowing in advance that you program may throw an exception in some particular code block. "---------this confuses me，if I don't know in advance that  program may throw an exception in some particular code block, I can't decide which section should add try-catch.

Comment: I've extended the answer, trying to address your comment.

Comment: for Java checked exceptions, they must be caught _or_ bubbled up (e.g. `void myMethod throws SomeCheckedEx { ... }`), basically saying "I'm not handling this issue, those who call me will have to".

Comment: @Rogue, true, you may "postpone" handling checked exceptions, but, at some point (upper in the stack), you will have to handle them anyway :) Unless you are developing a library that will just "forward" these exceptions to the caller.